# Kio estas la diferenco inter "fariĝis el" kaj "fariĝis al"?

Tags: verbs, phrasal

> Oni neniam eĉ scietis pri kio **fariĝis el** ili. (Mil naŭcent okdek
> kvar: p25)

La angla versio:

> One never had the smallest clue as to what had **happened to** them.

Ĉu ne **"fariĝis el"** devu esti **"fariĝis al"** ĉi tie? Cetere ĝenerale, kio estas la diferenco inter "fariĝis el" kaj "fariĝis al"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pli laŭlitera traduko estus: *pri kio **okazis al** ili.*

Oni faris ŝanĝon en la traduko, tute akcepteblan, ekzemple por specifa nuanco. Bonvolu noti ĉe Esperanto-tradukoj povus temi pri duagrada traduko, traduko el tradukita lingvo. Tamen se temas pri Donald Broadripp, tio ne estas tre verŝajna.

Estas alia formulado, traduko de: *what had **become from** them.*